# "Which" and "Whereas"

Tags: word-choice

I'm drafting a court motion and I'm having trouble starting the next sentence.

> Bill's only intention in this divorce is to cause severe emotional anguish. ..... Bill and Ms. Attorney made false statements and misrepresentations of material facts...

Would I say "Which Bill and Ms. Attorney" or Whereas Bill and Ms. Attorney"?

Comment: "[**Whereas**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whereas) Bill..." would imply you are talking about **another** Bill. How many Bills are there in the case? If it is the *same* Bill you don't need any conjunction. There is a *legal* use of **whereas** but that is rather different. This is plain English, no need to sound pompous in court.

Comment: I gather you're not an attorney. If you're in the US, the only court motions you're allowed to submit are for yourself. This is probably not the best idea. Hire an attorney to do the legal language for you. Advising you on specific legal language in court documents isn't something non-attorneys are allowed to do in the US.